# useRef.current.contains is not a function

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

I have a nav menu built with material-ui/core in Navbar.

I use useRef to track the position of clicked button on toggle menu close.
`anchorRef.current.contains(event.target)`

And I am getting `'Uncaught TypeError: anchorRef.current.contains is not a function'` .

I tried 'Object.values(anchorRef.current).includes(event.target)' instead, it always returns false.

-- update --

anchorRef.current.props Object.

```
withStyles {
    props:{
     aria-haspopup: "true"
     aria-owns: undefined
     children: "계정"
     className: "nav-menu--btn"
     onClic: f onClick()
     get ref: f()
      isReactWarning: true
      arguments: (...)
      caller: (...)
      length: 0
      name: "warnAboutAccessingRef"
     ...
    }, context{...}, refs{...}, ...}
```

### ToggleMenuList

```
const ToggleMenuList = ({ navAdminList, navAdminItems, classes }) => {
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);
  const anchorRef = useRef(null);
  const handleToggle = id => {
    setActiveId(id);
  };
  const handleClose = event => {
    if (anchorRef.current && anchorRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    setActiveId(null);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={`nav-menu--admin ${classes.root}`}>
        {navAdminList.map(e => (
          <div key={e.id}>
            <Button
              ref={anchorRef}
              aria-owns={activeId === e.id ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={() => handleToggle(e.id)}
            >
              {e.name}
            </Button>
            {activeId === e.id && (
              <ToggleMenuItems
                id={e.id}
                activeId={activeId}
                handleClose={handleClose}
                anchorRef={anchorRef}
                items={navAdminItems[e.id]}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ToggleMenuList);
```

### ToggleMenuItems

```
 const ToggleMenuItems = ({
      listId,
      activeId,
      handleClose,
      anchorRef,
      items,
    }) => {
      const isOpen = activeId === listId;
      const leftSideMenu = activeId === 3 || activeId === 4 ? 'leftSideMenu' : '';
    
      return (
        <Popper
          open={isOpen}
          anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
          keepMounted
          transition
          disablePortal
        >
          {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
            <Grow
              {...TransitionProps}
              style={{
                transformOrigin:
                  placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom',
              }}
              className={`toggle-menu ${leftSideMenu}`}
            >
              <Paper id="menu-list-grow">
                <ClickAwayListener
                  onClickAway={handleClose}
                >
                  <MenuList className="toggle-menu--list">
                    {items.map(e => (
                      <MenuItem
                        key={e.id}
                        className="toggle-menu--item"
                        onClick={handleClose}
                      >
                        <Link
                          to={e.to}
                          className="anchor td-none c-text1 toggle-menu--link"
                        >
                          {e.name}
                        </Link>
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </MenuList>
                </ClickAwayListener>
              </Paper>
            </Grow>
          )}
        </Popper>
      );
    };
    
    export default ToggleMenuItems;
```

```
react: ^16.8.6
react-dom: ^16.8.6
react-router-dom: ^4.3.1
@material-ui/core: ^3.1.2
```

Comment: what's inside of `anchorRef.current`? is there DOM Node or is there React class instance? it's up to `Button`s implementation, not `ToggleMenuItems`

Comment: I updated 'anchorRef.current' console log. I see  the react element as well as 'warnAboutAccessingRef' value. How can I work around with it ?

Comment: `warnAboutAccessingRef` is not an issue. It warns if you try to access it like `this.props.ref` inside that component(see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5742).

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `ToggleMenuItems` sets up global(`document`-level?) event listener on click to collapse Menu on clicking somewhere outside.

And you have a sibling button element. Clicking on that you want to keep menu expanded, right? So that was the point to use `.contains` in `onClick` to check if we are clicked outside of `ToggleMenuItems` but in scope of specific `Button`. The reason why it does not work: `<Button>` is custom class-based React component so it returns React component instance in ref. And it does not have any DOM-specific methods like `.contains`

You can rework you current approach: just stop bubbling event in case `Button` has been clicked. It would stop global event handler set by `ToggleMenuItems` to react.

```
const stopPropagation = (event) => event.stopPropagation();

const ToggleMenuList = ({ navAdminList, navAdminItems, classes }) => {
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);
  const anchorRef = useRef(null);
  const handleToggle = id => {
    setActiveId(id);
  };
  const handleClose = event => {
    setActiveId(null);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={`nav-menu--admin ${classes.root}`}>
        {navAdminList.map(e => (
          <div key={e.id}>
            <div onClick={stopPropagation}>
              <Button
                aria-owns={activeId === e.id ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={() => handleToggle(e.id)}
              >
                {e.name}
              </Button>
            </div>
            {activeId === e.id && (
              <ToggleMenuItems
                id={e.id}
                activeId={activeId}
                handleClose={handleClose}
                anchorRef={anchorRef}
                items={navAdminItems[e.id]}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ToggleMenuList);
```

I've put `stopPropagation` handler outside since it does not depend on any internal variable.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately, it does't work. ```handleClose``` from ToggleMenuItems is called before ```handleToggle``` from Button and then ```stopPropagation``` is called at last.

Comment: It calls ```handleClose``` function when mouse clicked out of  button scope (include all buttons). If I clicks another button, it won't call the function.